# Xslt generic to convert xml file to json

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I would like to create a generic xslt for my java application that converts an xml file into a json output.To try to make software as dynamic as possible

My xml input :

```
       <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <notice>
        <driver>
           <forward>
                <system>
                    <type>xxx</type>
                    <parameters>
                        <parameter key="test1">test1</parameter>
                        <parameter key="test2">test2</parameter>
                        <parameter key="test3">test3</parameter>
                        <parameter key="test4">test4</parameter>
                        <parameter key="test5">test5</parameter>
                        <parameter key="test6">test6</parameter>
                    </parameters>
                  <priority nil="true"></priority>
                </system>
            </forward>
        </driver>

        </notice>
```

This is xslt (Downloaded from the internet)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*[node()]">
        <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="detect" />
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="detect">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = name(current()) and name(following-sibling::*[1]) != name(current())">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content" />
                <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
                <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*[name() != name(current())]) &gt; 0">, </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = name(current())">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content" />
                    <xsl:if test="name(following-sibling::*) = name(current())">, </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*[1][name() = name(current())]">
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:text>" : [</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content" /><xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="count(./child::*) > 0 or count(@*) > 0">
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content" />
                <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*) &gt; 0">, </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="count(./child::*) = 0">
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:apply-templates select="."/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*) &gt; 0">, </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="obj-content">
        <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="attr" />
            <xsl:if test="count(@*) &gt; 0 and (count(child::*) &gt; 0 or text())">, </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./*" mode="detect" />
            <xsl:if test="count(child::*) = 0 and text() and not(@*)">
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="text()"/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="count(child::*) = 0 and text() and @*">
                <xsl:text>"text" : "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="text()"/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">, </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*" mode="attr">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node/@TEXT | text()" name="removeBreaks">
        <xsl:param name="pText" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(contains($pText, '&#xA;'))"><xsl:copy-of select="$pText"/></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($pText, '&#xD;&#xA;'), ' ')"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="removeBreaks">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '&#xD;&#xA;')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output json

```
      {
           "notice":{
              "driver":{
                 "forward":{
                    "system":{
                       "type":"xxx",
                       "parameters":{
                          "parameter":[
                             {
                                "key":"test1",
                                "text":"test1"
                             },
                             {
                                "key":"test2",
                                "text":"test2"
                             },
                             {
                                "key":"test3",
                                "text":"test3"
                             },
                             {
                                "key":"test4",
                                "text":"test4"
                             },
                             {
                                "key":"test5",
                                "text":"test5"
                             },
                             {
                                "key":"test6",
                                "text":"test6"
                             }
                          ]
                       },
                       "priority":{
                          "nil":"true"
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
        }
```

Instead, I would like to produce the following output

```
     {
           "notice":{
              "driver":{
                 "forward":{
                    "system":{
                       "type":"xxx",
                       "parameters":{
                          "parameter":[
                             {
                                "text1":"test1"
                             },
                             {
                                "test2":"test2"

                             },
                             {
                                "test3":"test3"

                             },
                             {
                                "test4":"test4"

                             },
                             {
                                "test5":"test5"

                             },
                             {
                                "test6":"test6"

                             }
                          ]
                       },
                       "priority":{
                          "nil":"true"
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
        }
```

Comment: So what is the task, to convert a certain XML input format to a certain JSON format or to convert any XML to JSON? Anyway, as you mention Java and XSLT 2.0 you could first check whether moving to Saxon 9.8 and XSLT 3.0 with the built-in support for https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#func-xml-to-json is not a starting point, where you could add templates to convert your input format to the one the `xml-to-json` function expects.

Comment: The activity involves converting any xml file to json using the xslt template I posted

Comment: I started today studying xslt .. I'm inexperienced

Comment: Since you're asking for a generic transform, there must be some generic rules by which you can describe (in prose) how the output you present is derived from the input you present.  I suspect you'll find it harder than you think to write such rules, especially such that it still works as you desire for more complex XML structures.  But do try it if you want to roll your own transform; the result will guide your implementation.

Comment: If you want to handle ANY xml input, then you'll need to think carefully about how to handle things that aren't present in your single use case. It's also unclear how your example can be generalized. For example your conversion of the parameters element only works for an element where (a) all the children have the same element name, (b) every child has exactly one attribute, (c) all those attributes have the same name, (d) you don't care what that attribute name is. That's not looking very generic to me.